# How do you block /etc/passwd file

Tags: linux

How do I block the `/etc/passwd` file for all users except for root?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: The easiest method, is to simply not allow any other users have access to the system.  I am sure I have seen several dups of this question, but they are not coming up in a search.  This is the closest I could find.   http://serverfault.com/questions/116281/in-linux-debian-did-the-passwords-etc-passwd-ever-been-stored-as-plain-text

Answer (score 6):

First, we should note that in modern systems, /etc/passwd doesn't actually contain any passwords, it just contains basic account information. On linux systems, the file that has the passwords is /etc/shadow, and it doesn't really contain the passwords, but cryptographically generated hashes of them (the file is /etc/master.passwd on FreeBSD based systems, including OSX).

By default both files should already have permissions that keep them safe, here is /etc/password on one of my linux systems:

```
jed@jed-bt:~$ ls -la /etc/passwd 
-rw-r--r--  1 root  root  1797 Feb 11 13:13 /etc/passwd
```

Note that you need to keep /etc/passwd world readable or things will break, as mentioned by a previous answer. So to reset the read/write permissions to these, you can run the command

```
chmod 644 /etc/passwd
```

If the file is owned by anyone other than root, you can also run

```
chown root:root /etc/passwd
```

to reset it. Of course you either have to run the `chown` and `chmod` commands as root, or using `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

It must be world readable or the system will break.

Answer (score 0):

As Dennis Williamson already stated: It must be readable. And all passwords are in "shadow" as hashed strings, so it's not really exploitable.

If you want even more security, consider using another authentication system like LDAP.