# Can I delete `mysql` os user which is created during mysql installation?

Tags: linux, mysql, centos7, user-accounts

I have installed MySQL Community Server 5.7.28 on a CentOS 7. I have observed that there is an OS level user `mysql` created during installation. As per our security team, we can have only one operational user on a server. I have checked that the default shell for `mysql` user is `/bin/false` & its password is locked. Still we are not allowed to have this user on the server. Can we change the ownership of the files from `mysql` user to our operational user & then delete the `mysql` user ?

I am still a novice in mysql. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/changing-mysql-user.html
but seriously, your "security team" is bonkers...

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/293217/our-security-auditor-is-an-idiot-how-do-i-give-him-the-information-he-wants . Maybe this gives you pointers on how to convince your security team to keep the user.

Comment: I honestly dont believe there is a security team.  I highly doubt there is a world that exists that would have someone remove the mysql user since it owns the directories and all files under /var/lib/mysql as well on mac it would probably just recreate the user.

Comment: @Lenniey - Thanks for the link! I had tested it on a test environment but it didn't work. The mysql server refused to start after changing the ownership of the files.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider - Thanks for pointing out to this link. I have been trying to convince them on three counts : 1) mysql user shell is `/bin/false`, 2) It has UID 40 so it can be classified as a system user. 3) The password of the user is locked, so we can't login anyways. Hoping for the best !

Comment: @Chris  - I agree to your point. Just having a hard time convincing them.

Comment: Did you do all the steps or just the `chown`?